# I need help designing a low voltage DC to AC circuit

Tags: converter, diy, low-voltage, dc-ac

Can anyone help me design a circuit that will perform low voltage DC to AC conversion? Ideally, I would like to have

- 3 to 6 VDC input (using AA batteries)
- Approximately 1 VAC output (less would be fine.)
- Output frequency must be in the range of 50-150 Hz.

I do not have enough electronics knowledge to design such a circuit, but I am capable of assembling it once the necessary components are identified.

This is for a high-school science project that I am assisting with.  The circuit is designed to simulate a human muscle EMG signal.  This converter circuit is not the student's project itself, but is needed to provide input into an EMG sensor that is being tested to operate a prosthetic device.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site, Paul. I had a clarification question - should this be a sine wave at 50-150Hz, or is the desired waveform more complex?

Comment: There are many schematics online, you could use 2 transistors, an op-amp, a logic gate (or two), or 555 timer IC to generate pulses of whatever width and frequency. Depending how fast do you need it, there are even many kits made with transistors or 555 timer which you simply plug-in and set to your desired pulse width and frequency.

Comment: Amplitude (peak, peak-to-peak, of RMS)?  Waveshape (sine square, triangle, etc.)?  Adjustable frequency over the range you mentioned, or tixed somewhere in the middle?  AND - what kind of load is the signal driving?  Impedance, current requirement, etc?  No matter what the answers are, the circuit will be relatively simple.

Comment: What you're describing is just about any digital audio player you can think of, the very computer or mobile device you've typed this question on included. No need for anything custom, and audio players tend to perform much better than most things you could cobble together quickly.

Comment: Wow - thank you all for the feedback!

Comment: Wow - thank you all for the feedback!

A fixed output signal (sine or square form) near to 100 Hz will work.  Output amplitude of 0.5-1.0 VAC peak-to-peak would be fine; we will attenuate it as needed. 

The idea to use a media playback device is brilliant. - I will start with that.

Ideally, we do need to build this circuit from scratch so that it can be embedded into our test device.  The online schematics I've seen deal with larger signals.  Any pointers to a useful circuit for this signal size, and/or the specific components that would go into it, would be *greatly* appreciated.

Comment: @AnalogKid, could you provide some suggestions for an example circuit and its components?  I can't speak to the impedance of the load.  Because this is being built into a larger/portable set-up, we'd like to use household batteries (perhaps 3 or 6 VDC, higher only if required) for power.  An output signal that is approx. 1.0 VAC (peak-to-peak), that is of sine form at a fixed frequency in the vicinity of 200 Hz is our goal.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you can reuse any of the existing Arduino-based music player projects for it - or even just use a mobile phone, and its headphone jack (or a suitable adapter for Lightning-only devices). You could also use a Bluetooth audio output module and just play the segments from any device with Bluetooth playback. Simplest way is to make playlists using VLC, since that works on Windows, MacOS, Linux, iOS and Android.

The audio output needs to be scaled down using a resistive divider of course, since the amplitude will be way too high otherwise.

You can download surface EMG waveforms online I'm sure - they are nothing like sine waves, by the way. Then some representative segments can be put on an SD card, and have the Arduino play them back, either via a PWM-based DAC, or an actual DAC (some Arduinos have them). Or put them into a VLC playlist and play on anything with a screen and a CPU that runs reasonably modern mainstream software :)

Comment: The idea to use a media playback device is brilliant. - I will start with that. However, we do need to build this circuit from scratch so that it can be embedded into our test device. 

A fixed output signal (sine or square form) near to 100 Hz will work. Output amplitude of 0.5-1.0 VAC peak-to-peak would be fine; we will attenuate it as needed. 

The online schematics I've seen deal with larger signals. Any pointers to a useful circuit for this signal size, and/or the specific components that would go into it, would be *greatly* appreciated.   

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 1):

If you are just creating a test signal for an EMG device a simple AC sine wave may do.  But looking at a few typical EMG wave forms they are much more than sine waves. Below are two typical EMG signals I was able to find:

[image]
.

FROM: https://medium.com/the-quest-for-a-life-like-prosthetic-hand/muscle-activity-processing-7715559aa1fb

[image]
.
FROM: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Characteristics-of-EMG-signal_fig1_232905752

Taken as a group the top EMG signal does look a bit like human speech, (or music). However a close up of a single pulse, second diagram, revels that they are quite complex.

If you want to simulate an AC signal close to an actual EMG pulse you may need something much more than a sine wave generator. One option is to use a device called an arbitrary wave form generator. A professional version of such a generator could run thousands of dollars. As a low cost alternative you could use an Arduino module and a bit of code. Nearly all Arduino systems are capable of generating an analog signal using a PWM scheme. There are a few with built in DAC outputs that can directly create almost any wave form needed.  Even though such a generated signal will be DC based on the Arduino power supply you can place a capacitor in series with the signal to make it a true AC signal.

Here is a tutorial using Arduino Due to create simple wave forms. You could easily create more complex wave forms by simply adjusting the numbers in the data arrays.
https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/due/simple-waveform-generator

Another circuit using an Arduino version with just resistors as the DAC is presented here:
http://pcarduino.blogspot.com/2013/11/arduino-r-2r-ladder-audio-dac.html

Both these ideas (and other references) were part of a Stack Exchange (Arduino) question several years back.
https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17848/is-it-possible-to-make-a-mathematical-function-generator-using-arduino

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I understand that natural EMG signals are a good bit more complex than simple sine waves, or even combinations of them.  But, our test sensor is a pretty simple thresholding device at the moment, that is sensitive only to absolute power and rate of change in power (on a relatively slow time scale).  What we need at the moment is to be able to build a circuit that we can use to repeatedly generate a sine wave of stable characteristics, so that we can refine our sensor.

Comment: Also keep in mind that even a simple square wave generated by any number of simple circuits (555 chip, single gate oscillators) can fairly easily be tuned down to become a good sine wave with just a few resistors and capacitors.  https://blog.mbedded.ninja/electronics/circuit-design/how-to-create-sine-waves-from-square-waves-and-rc-filters/

Answer (score 0):

Would this simple web page in a browser on a mobile device be good enough?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Ding</title>
    <script>
        const ding = function() {
            const FREQUENCY = 440
            const DURATION = 3  // Seconds. Remove `stop()` line to play forever.
            const MAX_VOLUME = .05   // Don't damage speakers, ears, etc. !!!

            const audio = new (window.AudioContext||window.webkitAudioContext)()
            const oscillator = audio.createOscillator()
            const gain = audio.createGain()
            const time = audio.currentTime

            oscillator.connect(gain).connect(audio.destination)
            oscillator.frequency.value = FREQUENCY
            gain.gain.value = MAX_VOLUME
            oscillator.start()
            oscillator.stop(time+DURATION)
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="ding()">Ding</button>
</body>
</html>
```